# "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted" while trying to click on sub-menus

Tags: selenium

I am automating `flipkart` site. My aim is to `login` to site and `logout` from site.

I **successfully logged in** but **unable to logout** as the logout link is under sub-menus (mousehover).

Attached the screenshot.

I tried all possible scenarios like using `Actions` class and `javascriptexecutor`.

Using `javascriptexecutor` it is working fine only if I manually place cursor on the sub-menu otherwise it is throwing an error.

[image: Image showing the problem with submenus and the browser console]

Comment: When you used the Actions class, did you add all of the actions, then do `.perform()`?

Answer (score 0):

I had no problem with getting this to work.

Here is the script using the [getting-started-with-selenium framework](https://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium)

```
@Config(url="http://flipkart.com", browser=Browser.FIREFOX)
public class TestFlikPart extends AutomationTest {
    @Test
    public void testLoginLogout() {
        String username = "<username>";
        String password = "<password>";

        click(By.cssSelector("a[href*='/login']"))
        .setText(By.cssSelector("input[name='email']"), username)
        .setText(By.cssSelector("input[name='password']"), password)
        .click(By.cssSelector("input[type='submit'][value='Login']"))

        .validatePresent(By.cssSelector("li.greeting-link > a"))

        .hoverOver(By.cssSelector("li.greeting-link > a"))

        .click(By.cssSelector("ul.account-dropdown a[href*='/logout']"))

        // should be logged out now.
        .validatePresent(By.cssSelector("a[href*='/login']"));
    }
}
```

I think MrTi is correct - i think you might have forgotten to do `.perform()` on the action.  A further explanation on the `hoverOver()` method, this is what that method contains -

```
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(by)).perform();
```

Comment: Hi MrTi/sircapsalot, below is the code i implemented. I used perform() also.  
driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com/");  
driver.findElement(By.xpath()).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath()).sendKeys("username");
driver.findElement(By.xpath().sendKeys("passwd");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath()).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);   
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath());
WebElement subLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath());
builder.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).build().perform();      Thread.sleep(5000);
subLink.click();