# Getting exception: Unable to locate element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a script to automate login and logout for site [www.flipkart.com](http://www.flipkart.com). But my script is failing and giving exception:
 `Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Logout"}`
I am not able to figure out what is the issue. Can anyone tell what is the issue with my locator.
Below is my code:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
System.out.print("log1");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fk-mainhead-id']/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[6]/a"));
System.out.print("log2");
Action action = builder.moveToElement(element).build();
action.perform();
System.out.print("log3");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
 driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout")).click();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted" while trying to click on sub-menus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679748/element-is-not-currently-visible-and-so-may-not-be-interacted-while-trying-to)

Answer (score 1):

You're in luck.. recently, i had helped an individual with logging in and out of flipkart.  Here was the script:

```
@Config(url="http://flipkart.com", browser=Browser.FIREFOX)
public class TestFlipKart extends Conductor {
    @Test
    public void testLoginLogout() {
        String username = "<username>";
        String password = "<password>";

        click(By.cssSelector("a[href*='/login']"))
        .setText(By.cssSelector("input[name='email']"), username)
        .setText(By.cssSelector("input[name='password']"), password)
        .click(By.cssSelector("input[type='submit'][value='Login']"))

        .validatePresent(By.cssSelector("li.greeting-link > a"))

        .hoverOver(By.cssSelector("li.greeting-link > a"))

        .click(By.cssSelector("ul.account-dropdown a[href*='/logout']"))

        // should be logged out now.
        .validatePresent(By.cssSelector("a[href*='/login']"));
    }
}
```

mind you, this is using the [Conductor](http://conductor.ddavison.io) framework.  You can translate the CSS selectors I had in there to your script.